# How can I collect a number of tweets between 2 given dates using tweepy?

Tags: python, json, api, tweepy, tweets

For example, I want to collect 20 tweets each day from 1st June to today's date but right now I am only able to view the 20 recent tweets of today's date.

```
def get_tweets_and_tones_json(searchTerm, NoOfTerms):

output = []
geo = "21.1498134,79.0820556,1045km"
start_date = datetime.date(2020, 6, 1)
end_date = datetime.date.today()
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,q=searchTerm,count=NoOfTerms, geocode=geo,lang='en', 
                    since= start_date,until = end_date).items(20)
for i,tweet in enumerate(tweets):
    tweetedText = tweet.text
    
    jsonFile1 = analyze_tone(tweetedText)
    x = tweet.created_at
    print(tweetedText,'\n', x)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make it meaningful even without a title.

Comment: With the public API you can't search older than 6-9 days (source: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators)